# C++ constructor prototype parameter

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arguments, prototype

For example, there is a class foo :

```
class foo {
public: 
      foo (int = 10);
.....
}
```

The prototype of the constructor  has "int = 10" inside. So, what does it mean? Int is just an integer type, isn't? So, isn't  that illegal to assign a value to it?  I was trying to find such an example in Prata's book, and everywhere else, but I didn't  find the explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can omit the name of parameter in function declaration (in definition too), but still you are able to specify default value of that parameter.

Consider:

```
void f(int x = 10) {
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

void g(int = 10);

void g(int x) {
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

int main() {
    f();
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
10
10
```

The same situation is in the constructor case.

Comment: Good answer. I completely missed the fact that no name was specified and thought the OP did not know about default arguments in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> So, isn't that illegal to assign a value to it?

There is absolutely no *assignment* involved here. The `=` character can have quite different meanings in C++:

- Assignment: `i = 0;`
- Initialisation: `int i = 0;`
- Making a member function pure virtual: `virtual void f() = 0;`
- Specifiying [default arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments): `void f(int i = 0);`

The latter is what you have encountered. A constructor can have default arguments like any other normal function.